# Remove a whole table if all rows are removed using jQUery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that contains dates within one table cell on each row. I use Javascript to detect today's date, and if the dates in the cell are before today's date, I remove the whole table row.

```
$(function(){
  $('.table-cell-containing-date').each(function(key,value){
    var currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var date = new Date($(value).text());
    if(date < currentDate){
        $(value).parent().remove();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm trying to amend this so that once all dates in the table for a particular month are in the past (and therefore removed), the whole table itself should be removed.

I don't even know where to start to be honest. I need to check the whole table to see if any rows in each table exist after the above Javascript has fired, and if they don't, remove the whole table.

I've setup a Fiddle where you will see the first row being removed because the date is in the past. https://jsfiddle.net/67ktea40/1/

Many thanks in advance,

J

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/3rpdhLkw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the two line as below

```
$(function(){
    $('.production-date').each(function(key,value){
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var date = new Date($(value).text());
        if(date < currentDate){
            $(value).parent().remove();
            var count = $('.tour-dates-table tr').length;
            if(count<=2) $('.tour-dates-table').remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Updated version of answer for your question

```
$(function(){
    $('.production-date').each(function(key,value){
        var currentDate = new Date();
        currentDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        var date = new Date($(value).text());
        if(date < currentDate){
            var currenttable = $(value).parent().closest('table');
            $(value).parent().remove();
            var count = $(currenttable).children('tr').length;
            if(count<=2) { $(currenttable).remove(); }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Sasikumar. Just one question... I have multiple tables with the class of .tour-dates-table How do I check each .tour-dates-table independently, and remove that one table if it is empty? I've added your markup to https://jsfiddle.net/67ktea40/2/ and also added a second table... you can see the first table should be hidden because all the dates are in the past, but because there is a second table with dates in the future, all tables are showing. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update, Sasikumar. This works perfectly.

Comment: Hi Sasikumar. I've just noticed that for some reason the code you wrote is removing the entire table as soon as one tr is removed. IE. As soon as one tr has a date in the past, it is removing the whole table, even if there are multiple TR's still with dates in the future. I've setup a Fiddle so can you see this. https://jsfiddle.net/g6a2nt0k/ You'll notice there are two dates in the table... one in the past, one in the future, so it should still be showing the one in the future, but instead it hides the entire table. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's empty and them [remove](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_remove.asp) it

```
  function deleteIfEmpty() {
    var tbody = $("table tbody");
    if (tbody.children().length == 0) {
       $("table").remove();
    }
  }
```

And call it after every row-removal.

Answer (score 0):

Check if table has no tr then remove it

```
if (!$('table').find('tr').length){
    $('table').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the table `.has()` no `production-date` element, then remove entire table.

```
var table = $('table.tour-dates-table');
if (table.has(".production-date").length == 0) {
  table.remove();
}
```

In [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w95nqyht/), as I have removed all `tr` containing `.production-date`

Answer (score 0):

First bind an event to the table's container `div`.And then check for table rows length.If its zero remove the table.:

```
$('#container-div').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    if($('#myTable tr').length==0){
       $('#myTable').remove();
    }
});
```